# Where/how are iteratee values actually being executed?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using Underscore.js to expand my knowledge and understanding of more complex javascript concepts and was hoping someone could help me understand how exactly the _.iteratee function gets executed in a specific example.

Here is that example, with comments about my understanding thus far.

I am using the _.map function like so:

```
_.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key){ return num * 3; });
=> [3, 6, 9]
```

At the very bottom are the relevant functions being used, with some insignificant ones like _.keys being left out.

My understanding is this:

1. Within the _.map function, the first instance of `iteratee` within the body of the function is being set like so: `iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);` which based on the `_.iteratee` function (because an function is being passed into _.map) should evaluate to `createCallback(value, context, argCount)`.
2. The next time the `iteratee` variable (which should now be a callback function) is used in the _.map function is here:  `results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);`.

This is where I get lost.

Questions:

1. Assuming my #1 assumption above is indeed correct, when we get to this line of the _.map function inside the loop: `results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);` what we are *actually* calling is `createCallback(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj)`. So does `obj[currentKey]` get passed to the `func` parameter in createCallback?  (Doesn't seem to make sense).
2. If the above is true, where I get lost is, when `createCallback` is evaluated, what is the value of `obj` which in `createCallback` is the `argCount`. I do not understand which part of the switch statement in `createCallback` gets referenced.

Which switch statement gets called in this case?

If I have that, I should be able to complete the trace to the closure inside createCallback.  Any additional information you may provide to guide me is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Functions

_.map

```
  _.map = _.collect = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    if (obj == null) return [];
    iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
    var keys = obj.length !== +obj.length && _.keys(obj),
        length = (keys || obj).length,
        results = Array(length),
        currentKey;
    for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
      results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
    }
    return results;
  };
```

createCallback

```
  var createCallback = function(func, context, argCount) {
    if (context === void 0) return func;
    switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount) {
      case 1: return function(value) {
        return func.call(context, value);
      };
      case 2: return function(value, other) {
        return func.call(context, value, other);
      };
      case 3: return function(value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, value, index, collection);
      };
      case 4: return function(accumulator, value, index, collection) {
        return func.call(context, accumulator, value, index, collection);
      };
    }
    return function() {
      return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
  };
```

_.iteratee

```
  _.iteratee = function(value, context, argCount) {
    if (value == null) return _.identity;
    if (_.isFunction(value)) return createCallback(value, context, argCount);
    if (_.isObject(value)) return _.matches(value);
    return _.property(value);
  };
```

Comment: *"[...] what we are actually calling is `createCallback(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj)`"* Nope. `iteratee` is the **return value** of `createCallback(iteratee, context)`, not `createCallback` itself. Anywhere you have something like `return foo();`, the function `foo` is called first an its return value is returned. So for example if `foo()` returns `5`, we are basically doing `return 5;`. The return value can be another function, which is the case with `createCallback`.

Comment: @FelixKling - Ah yes, I am definitely forgetting this very important piece here. This is making much more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular line,

```
results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
```

`iteratee` will be actually called like this

```
iteratee(<actual value of obj[currentKey]>, currentKey, obj);
```

So, `obj` will not be passed on to the `iteratee` function.

In your case, since you are passing an object as the first argument, on each and every iteration the `results` accumulation line would evaluate something similar to this

```
results[0] = iteratee(1, "one", obj);
results[1] = iteratee(2, "two", obj);
results[2] = iteratee(3, "three", obj);
```

iteratee = 
And when this line is executed,

```
_.iteratee(iteratee, context);
```

`iteratee` is actually the function you passed as one of the arguments to `_.map`. And since you are not passing a `context` object explicitly, by default, the value would be `undefined`. So,

```
if (context === void 0) return func;
```

check in the `createCallback` function will evaluated to `true` (since `undefined == void 0`), the function you actually passed to the `_.map` will be used as the call back function.

Comment: The last part is not correct. `_.iteratee` is called as `iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);`, and since `argCount` is not set, so it defaults to `3`: `switch (argCount == null ? 3 : argCount)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Just realized that was wrong. Actually, it will return the `func`, since the `context` is `undefined`. So `if (context === void 0) return func;` will be evaluated

Comment: @FelixKling Me too, at first. Just updated the answer now. BTW, it looks like too broad to me, what do you think?

Comment: I think it's OK. Just seems to be some confusion around higher-order functions.

Comment: @thefourtheye and FelixKling - thank you both very much. What really confused me is how even though arguments are being passed, not all of them are actually used, or need to be used! This definitely helped and I see this clearer now. Thanks, Gents.

Comment: @productionQA: Ah yes, that's another thing. In JS, the formal parameters of a function (e.g. `bar, baz` in `function foo(bar, baz){}`) are basically just for conveniently accessing the first and second argument passed to the function. JS does not enforce arguments. A caller can pass more or less arguments (i.e. `foo(); foo(1); foo(1,2); foo(1,2,3); ...` are all valid ways to call `foo`).